# Install Microsoft SQL Server 2012 express edition

Tags: sql-server-2012

I tried to install MS SQL server, yesterday on my Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit OS machine, following the instructions provided in a PDF by a company that has done it before.

Everything seemed to say it installed ok.  However it didn't seem to install SQL Server Management Studio which is used for a lot of the exercises I am required to do and quite useful in general.

Has this happened to anybody else.  Has anyone got any advice for what I can do to fix this.

I did notice that my machine seems to have MS SQL Server 2008 for some reason, I think it must have already been there and is conflicting, perhaps I should uninstall it.  What do you think?

I hope you's can help.

Thanks

KR
Sharpie

Comment: SQL Server 2008 will not conflict with your 2012 instance.

Comment: Can you post the instructions you were using, since they weren't from MS directly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you downloaded and installed only the db, and not the one with "Tools".  The Tools is the one that includes SSMS.  No worries you can go here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062 and download the Tools separately and install it.  Expanded the "Details" of the page and this will let you know about the different files you can download.

Comment: Hello Everyone. Thank you all.  Yes it seems like MS split out the download.  Now SQL Server Management Studio needs to be downloaded separately.  Thanks for your help.  However, I now have a different problem.  I''m trying to download ODBC driver for SQL Server and all the pages for download for that product seem to say no longer available.  Does anybody have a working download link for this please? I'll give you an example of a broken one where I'm trying to download from:

Comment: Hello Everyone. Thank you all.  Yes it seems like MS split out the download.  Now SQL Server Management Studio needs to be downloaded separately.  Thanks for your help.  However, I now have a different problem.  I''m trying to download ODBC driver for SQL Server and all the pages for download for that product seem to say no longer available.  Does anybody have a working download link for this please? e.g. of downloads for 64 bit that don't work: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/search/result.aspx?q=odbc+driver+for+sql+server&form=dlc , I tried a few on that page.